# What references are required for app.RunIISPipeline() in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

When I try to use the following:

```
app.RunIISPipeline();
```

Visual Studio suggests that I add `"Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS": "1.0.0-beta8-15609"`. If I add that to my project.json file, I am then presented with the following error:

> The type 'IApplicationBuilder' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'...

If I then add `"Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"` to my project.json file. I still receive the same error.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

This snippet is from the ASP.net 5 [documentation.](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

```
// Enable the IIS native module to run after the ASP.NET middleware components.
// This call should be placed at the end of your Startup.Configure method so that
// it doesn't interfere with other middleware functionality.
app.RunIISPipeline();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the design change, ASP.NET Core apps no longer support that API. You can check GitHub repo aspnet/Hosting issues,

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/323

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/491

Comment: @CoolBreeze I also updated. They made last minute change.

Comment: hrmmm you seem to be correct. If that is indeed the case how do I go about resolving this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126535/404-2-exception-not-being-caught-by-asp-net-core

Comment: @CoolBreeze, reply to your other question.